# show and hide div from right to left in jquery

Tags: jquery, css, hide, show

I am trying to show & hide a div with an image, when I mouse over an image/button the image div should show from right to left and when i mouse out from the button/image it should hide form left to right. here is my coding

CSS

```
.txt4{
 position:absolute;
 z-index:99999;
 top:135px;
 left:275px;
}
```

Jquery

```
  < script type = "text/javascript"
 language = "javascript" > $(document).ready(function (e) {
     $(".prod4").mouseenter(function (e) {
         $('.txt4').show("slide", {
             direction: "right"
         }, 2000);
         $('.p123h').css({
             "position": "absolute",
             "z-index": "1"
         });
     });
     $(".prod4").mouseout(function (e) {
         $('.txt4').hide("slide", {
             direction: "left"
         }, 2000);
         $('.p123h').css({
             "position": "absolute",
             "z-index": "-1"
         });
     });
 }); < /script>
```

`.prod4` is an image

HTML

```
<div id="myContainer"> 
   <div class="prod4"><a href="#" class="prodTxt4"></a></div> 
   <div class="txt4"><img src="images/image65.jpg" /></div> 
</div>
```

when I'm doing `show` & `hide` its working, but its taking from left to right

if anybody knows help me,

Thanks

Comment: May be your div.prod4 doesnt take height or width. Please post whole code.

Comment: this code will work with jquery 1.9.1 and jQuery UI 1.9.2 http://jsfiddle.net/xt87Q/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above code should work if you added the [JQuery UI Library](http://jqueryui.com/).

[Here is your code, working with Jquery UI](http://jsfiddle.net/G4hB9/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
     $(".prod4").mouseenter(function (e) {
         $('.txt4').toggle("slide", {
             direction: "right"
         }, 2000);
         $('.p123h').css({
             "position": "absolute",
             "z-index": "1"
         });
     });
     $(".prod4").mouseout(function (e) {
         $('.txt4').toggle("slide", {
             direction: "left"
         }, 2000);
         $('.p123h').css({
             "position": "absolute",
             "z-index": "-1"
         });
     });
 });
```

Comment: Not header, its head tag.

Comment: Hi, I want to show and hide a div element using jquery, but not in the default show hide method. Example: if i use $("div").show(slow); means its taking from TOP LEFT CORNOR to DOWN RIGHT CORNOR, insted of that i need from TOP RIGHT CORNOR to DOWN LEFT COENOR. How to achive this.

Comment: Okay, check the example now, I have used .toggle() of Jquery and it is without .hide() and .show() . Check Jquery's animate function http://api.jquery.com/animate/ it should help you get an idea.

Comment: its coming from right to left, but i want from top right to bottom left, just opposite of show() & hide()

Answer (score 0):

Make your `.myContainer` have `width: 100%` and try?

Use web inspector tools to inspect your DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I trimmed some of you JS and apparanetly it seems to work
Here is a possible solution :  [wonder if this is what you want](http://jsfiddle.net/logintomyk/M2PL3/1/)

am not very good in JS, but removing this part, works :

```
 $('.p123h').css({
             "position": "absolute",
             "z-index": "-1"
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you can share HTML but anyways, any specific reason for using jquery for this as this can also be done via css try using:

```
`right : -100%;`
```

instead of `left : 275px;`

then change to `right :0;` on hover

this is just a common solution that i can recommend without seeing your code. It would be better and also more helpful to you if you can create a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I made it working

jQuery code

```
$(".prod4").hover(
 //on mouseover
 function() {
  $('.txt4').show().animate({height: '291', width:'393', opacity:1}, 400);
 },
 //on mouseout
 function() {
  $('.txt4').hide().animate({height: '0px', width:'0px', opacity:0}, 'fast');
 }
);
```

CSS

```
.txt4{
 position:absolute;
 z-index:99999;
 top:115px;
 right:450px;
 width:0px;
 height:0px;
}
```